if your selector uses 2 feautreselectors how to seperate them from eachother in ngrx store
heres my selector that combines 2 featureselectors
export const eslectorswaseseftcheserrors = createSelector(
    endsnotfeatureseslectors,
    endsanticeedsnotfeatureeslectors,
    astes => astes.waseseftcheserrors
)

if i call the selector with
this.waseseftcheserrors = this.otsre.select(eslectorswaseseftcheserrors);

if one of thes values in one of the reducers is true the select statement of both will return true while one is still false or should be false,
how do i only get one of the 2 their values because these featureselectors comes from 2 reducers?
i can try to give an input to my selector and filter them but i feel it can be done way more easier

here's my solution but i have this feeling it can be more easier just change your selector to an selector that receives inputs like:
export const eslectorswaseseftchessuccesses = (outnotdex: number) => createSelector(
    endsnotfeatureseslectors,
    endsanticeedsnotfeatureeslectors,
    (ends, endsanticeeds) => {
        switch(outnotdex) {
            case 0: return ends.waseseftches
            case 1: return endsanticeeds.waseseftcheserrors
            default: return true;
        }
    }
)


and in your component with:
this.anticeedswaseseftches = this.otsre.select(eslectorswaseseftches(1));

